# What am I doing wrong with this Regex?

Tags: php, regex

To be honest, I don't really *get* RegEx. So I'm completely oblivious as to where I'm going wrong here.

I'm looking for a RegEx that accepts alphanumeric characters **only** (and underscores, it's for usernames). I've searched around here and found numerous example RegExes that I've tried and not one of them has worked.

Among others, which I've mostly gotten from answers around here, I've tried

```
^[a-zA-Z0-9_]*$
/[^a-z_\-0-9]/i
/^\w+$/
```

To match these, I've tried (with each of the regexes)

```
   if(preg_match("/^\w+$/", $username)) { 
     //don't accept 
   }
```

and

```
 if(!preg_match("/^\w+$/", $username)) {
      //don't accept
    }
```

and

```
if(preg_match("/^\w+$/", $username) == 1) {
      //don't accept
    }
```

and

```
if(preg_match("/^\w+$/", $username) == 0) {
  //don't accept
}
```

etc...
Each and every single time it's accepting special characters (I've tried &, $, ^, and %).

What exactly am I doing wrong here? Is it the format of the RegEx? Is it how I'm asking it to check?

Also, what exactly is the return type I get if it's found special characters? (i.e One I **don't** want to accept)

Comment: You probably want `/^[[:alnum:]_]+$/`.

Comment: Try this `if (preg_match('/[^\\w]/', $username) == 1) `. For easy testing have a look at [this](http://www.functions-online.com/preg_match.html)

Comment: All your regex patterns are correct. Your usage or processing logic is wrong. Possibly elsewhere,

Comment: @CodeGnome No, that will not solve op's problem - can you point out why his/her other patterns are *wrong* whereas yours is correct?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[`preg_match`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match.php) returns 1 if the input string matched the pattern you gave, and 0 if it didn't.

You want each character in your usernames to be alphanumeric (plus underscore). One PCRE way of expressing that is with a [character class](http://php.net/manual/en/regexp.reference.character-classes.php) inside square brackets, like this one: `[A-Za-z0-9_]`. There are a couple of ways you could use this basic class to do what you want.

One way is a "negative" search: try to match a *non*-alphanumeric character, and if you do, then the test fails. For this, we just add a carat at the front of the character class. This means we're matching any character *not* in that set.

So, the following pattern matches "any non-alphanumeric, non-underscore character." Here, a match means an *invalid* username:

```
if (preg_match('/[^A-Za-z0-9_]/',  $username)) {
    // invalid username
}
```

Or, you could do the opposite kind of match, where you give a pattern for a valid username and check if you match that. This time, we don't change the character class itself at all, but we add the `+` quantifier after it, meaning we're matching *one or more* of the "good" characters.

Additionally, we wrap the `^` and `$` beginning-and-end-of-string anchors around our pattern. (It's a little confusing, but a carat at the beginning of a pattern has a completely different meaning from a carat at the beginning of a character class, within the brackets).

The end result is a pattern that means: "1 or more alphanumeric characters (plus underscore) and *nothing else*." A match on this one means a *valid* username:

```
if (preg_match('/^[A-Za-z0-9_]+$/', $username)) {
    // valid username
}
```

Comment: The syntactic difference between the two expressions is extremely slight - would be nice to point out explicitly what the difference is.

Comment: Thank you, and thank you for explaining it really well. I went for the 'positive' approach to it. Stay positive, I say.

Answer (score 2):

```
if (preg_match("^[a-zA-Z0-9_]+$", $username) === 1) {
    // Good username
}
else {
    // Bad username
}
```

The use of the strict equality operator (===) means we're comparing what preg_match() returns to 1, the number, not the boolean value. If it returns a 0, it means there are no matches, a boolean false, an error occored. Check out the page for `preg_match` for more information: http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match.php

Comment: -1 explains nothing. Zilch text. SO isn't a code exchange. And OP obviously has problems with understanding the logic.

Comment: @mario I disagree. The explicit "Good username" and `else` with "Bad username" serve to demonstrate how the comparison should work.  Look at op's very first example - he/she has the logic backwards.  Regardless, this hardly deserves a downvote.

Comment: @Madbreaks: Actually it deserves two now. Not only was the retarded `===` copied post-factum from the other answer, it's also pointless. The function can only return one trueish value in this context. What other purpose does the strict comparison serve here than cargo cult programming?

Comment: @mario allows for greater control and understanding of how preg_match() works, which allows OP to defensively program. It's more explicit and it should be a habit for PHP developers for any function that has more than one possible return type.

Comment: @mario Your disgust for non-lazy programming has clouded your vision. You're can't see the value in the answer, you can only see semantics.

Comment: Nice common place. Explain the defense here. What ambiguity does it solve? In this very example? Because that seems to be the only textual info in your answer. You also forgot to explain why you copied it sans attribution.

Comment: You accuse me of plagiarism as if the === operator was entirely the idea of another answer. FYI, the edit came from after glancing over the preg_match page from php.net again, which I actually did attribute in my post, so your point is worthless.

Comment: @Madbreaks Don't wanna nitpick needlessly, but it appears your zealotry for super-exact coding has clouded yours. The regex lacks delimiters, will result in an error when run. And this is precisely what happens when people focus on trivia and bending a dynamic language into a strictly typed one; actual solving becomes an afterthought.

Answer (score 0):

Per [the PHP manual](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match.php) *preg_match* will return 0 if it can't find a successful match with your regex and FALSE if en error occurs. So if you want to make sure you're testing for 0, and not something which can evaluate to false, you should use the `===` operator.

If you only want letters and underscores you can use a character class of `[a-z_]` which specifies that the range of characters for a to z and the `_` symbol will match. And the `+` following the class specifies that you want one or multiple of the same. The `^` says the pattern must match from the beginning of the text, while the `$` says that the pattern must match up until the end of the text.

```
if (preg_match("/^[a-z_]+$/i", $text_variable) === 1) {
    //"A match was found.";
} else {
    //"A match was not found.";
}
```

Comment: No, `preg_match` returns *zero* if it can't find a match.

Answer (score 0):

Regex is very easy to understand if you get the basics :)

I'll try to explain to you all three expressions you tried:

1. With **^[a-zA-Z0-9_]*$** string will be matched which:

   ```
   ^ // from the beginning...

   [a-zA-Z0-9_] // contains only characters a-z or A-Z or 0-9 or _ sign

   * // and has 0 or more of such characters

   $ // to the end
   ```

   Matched strings for example:

   ```
   (empty string - since you told 0 or more characters)
   abc09
   fidjwieofoj4fio3j4fiojrfioj3ijfo
   000000000000000000000
   __________
   and_many_many_more_as_long_as_they_contain_alpha_characters_and___sign
   ```
2. With **/[^a-z_-0-9]/i** string will be matched which:

   ```
   [^a-z_\-0-9]
   // ^ means "the opposite" so that subset describes characters
   // which are not included in it
   // (are not a-z or _ sign, or - dash sign, or 0-9 numbers)

   i modifier
   // stands for case insensitive, all letters are treated as lowercase
   ```

   You did not add * or ? or + after the subset so basically you are looking for one character only, and because you did not put your regexp between ^ and $ signs, this expression will finally match any text which contains at least one character which is not A-Z or a-z, or _ sign, or - dash sign, or 0-9 numbers.

   Matched strings for example:

   ```
   !
   a>a
   A<9
   ffffffffff.dflskfdfd
   00000,
   ]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]
   and so-on
   ```
3. With **/^\w+$/** string will be matched which:

   ```
   ^ // from the beginning
   \w // contains only characters a-z or A-Z or 0-9 or _ sign
   + // and the string must be at least 1 character long
   $ // to the end
   ```

   Probably the most useful regular expression. Remember, **\w** is just an alias for [a-zA-Z0-9_]. This regexp will match only whole string which is not empty and contains only alphanumeric characters and _ sign.

   Matched strings for example:

   ```
   mike
   alice
   bob10
   0000000000
   1111
   9
   php
   user_example
   ```

Hope that helps. To you, most useful expression imvho to match valid usernames would be **/^\w{3,15}$/** as it would match any string which is 3 to 15 characters long and consist only of alphanumeric characters and the underscore sign (a-z A-Z 0-9 _).

Try this:

```
<?php

function isValidUsername($username)
{
    return preg_match('/^\w{3,15}$/', $username) == 1;
}

echo isValidUsername('mike999') ? 'Yes' : 'No' , '<br>';
echo isValidUsername('alice!') ? 'Yes' : 'No';
```

Cheers.